# ConTeXt: Remove whitespace between Chapters in Table of Context

Tags: table-of-contents, context, context-lmtx

I need to remove whitespace between Chapters in Table of Content, but keep the space between  frontmatter and bodymatter. Can anyone enlighten me how to do this, please?

I am writing book that only has chapters and the whitespace between them appears to be jarring, hence the need to remove it.

MWE is as following:

```
\setupindenting[yes, 1em]

\setuphead[chapter][style={\bfa}]
\setuphead[chapter][header=empty]
\setuphead[title]
      [incrementnumber=yes,  % keep track of the number
      number=no]            % but don't show it
\setuphead[title][style={\bfa}]
\setuphead[title][header=empty]
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={title,chapter},alternative=c]
\setuplist[title][headnumber=no]
\setuplist[chapter][headnumber=yes, margin=0em,width=1.5em]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

\starttitle[title=Table of Content]
\placecontent[criterium=all]
\stoptitle

\starttitle[title=Preface]
\input knuth
\stoptitle

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

\startchapter[title=Chapter One]
\input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Chapter Two]
\input knuth
\stopchapter

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `before` and `after` keys in `\setuplist` to remove the space between chapters (or set them up as you want them). You can then use `\writebetweenlist` to add the extra space where you need it. I give an example with no space between chapters (or titles) and 2cm extra space between the frontmatter and bodymatter:

```
\setupindenting[yes,1em]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [style={\bfa},
   header=empty]

\setuphead
  [title]
  [incrementnumber=yes,
   number=no]

\setuphead
  [title]
  [style={\bfa},
   header=empty]

\setupcombinedlist
  [content]
  [list={title,chapter},
   alternative=c]

\setuplist
  [title]
  [headnumber=no]

\setuplist
  [chapter]
  [headnumber=yes,
   margin=0em,
   width=1.5em,
   before={\blank[none]},
   after={\blank[none]}]

\setupalign[hz,hanging]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

\starttitle[title=Table of Content]
\placecontent[criterium=all]
\stoptitle

\starttitle[title=Preface]
\input knuth
\stoptitle

\stopfrontmatter

\writebetweenlist
  [chapter]
  {\blank[2cm]}

\startbodymatter

\startchapter[title=Chapter One]
\input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Chapter Two]
\input knuth
\stopchapter

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

The table of contents now look like this:

[image: toc]